# How can I send requests to JSON?

Tags: json, dynamic, ionic-framework

I'm coding a mobile application with ionic. I have to get a data (daily changing data) from a web page with JSON, but I want to get old data too. For example:

```
data.json?date=2016-11-10
data.json?data=2016-12-10
```

How can I send request to JSON?

Comment: You want to send a JSON by method GET?

Comment: Yes, i want to send date data and i want to get content of that day by json.

Comment: But your question is how to get the answer to that call ??

Comment: for example, i ve a database, with fields, id and name, now in my mobile application, i ve a list with id's. If you click id 1, you will get the name with id = 1. i m using names.json to get the data, but names file must get the id from the client, so it must be something like that; names.json?id=1 and you will get the name of row with id=1.

Answer (score 0):

To send data from PHP, once you get your data from the database, the array will apply `json_encode($array);` and to return you put `return json_encode ($ array);`

Try this!

```
var date = '2016-11-10';
$http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: data.php,
       params: {date: date},
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json"

 }).then(function(response) {

 });
```

Comment: can you give me an example of data.json code, because i ve to use php to connect database, how can i do it in json file?

Comment: Edit my answer!

Comment: Of course, you should do such a file on your server or on your localhost: Usuarios.php and that file returns all of the database but in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The question is confusing, so I'm not sure how to answer. If you are having trouble formatting a request to a REST service, you will need to find out how the service expects the date  to be formatted in your field-value pair i.e:

```
date=2016/11/10 or date=20161110
```

If those don't work, this answer may help [The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) 
 
However, if you are actually wondering how to serialize a date in JSON, this link may help http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use services for ajax requests.

Create a Service

```
//Service
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('appName')
        .factory('appAjaxSvc', appAjaxSvc);

    appAjaxSvc.$inject = ['$http', '$log', '$q'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function appAjaxSvc($http, $log, $q) {

        return {
            getData:function (date){

              //Create a promise using promise library
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http({
                    method: 'GET', 
                    url:'/url?date='+date
                }).
                success(function(data, status, headers,config){
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers,config){
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            },
        };
    }
})();
```

Then Use it in Controller

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('appName')
        .controller('appCtrl', appCtrl);

    appCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'appAjaxSvc'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function appCtrl($scope, $stateParams, appAjaxSvc) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'appCtrl';

        activate();

        ////////////////

        function activate() {

            appAjaxSvc.getData(date).then(function(response) {
                //do something
            }, function(error) {
                alert(error)
            });

        }
    }
})();
```